# count number of coordinate points in c++

Tags: c++11, vector, point

i have a vector which stores a list of co-ordinate points. I would like to count the occurrence of each point within defined tolerance  limit.
Let us say tolerance limit has  been defined as 10 for both X and Y value. and the vector contains { (100, 200), ( 110, 205 ), ( 115, 215 ), ( 120, 220 ), ( 100, 200 ), ( 150, 160 ) }. Now my desired output is
( 100, 200 )   3 
( 110, 205 )   4
( 115, 215 )   3
( 120,220  )   2
( 150, 160 )   1

The first co-ordinate count 3 includes (100, 200), ( 110, 205 ) {reason being the value is within the range 100 +- 10 and 200 +- 10 } and ( 100, 200 )
Here efficiency is high priority

Comment: The data structure you are likely looking for is [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

Comment: thanks for the reference. I think it would be perfect solution. Googling around I discovered i would need boost library to implement this data structure. Is there any native way to do this in c++??

Comment: You don't *need* boost library. C++ is Turing-complete, you can use it to implement anything from scratch if you are so inclined. On the other hand, if you don't want to implement everything from scratch, then you would look for a third-party library that does what you need - and then you would, naturally, take a dependency on said library and anything it in turn depends on. That's the way software development works.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I decided to use the boost library for rtree. Here is my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the solution of this problem using boost. I am posting the code here in case someone needs similar solution in future.

```
    #include<set>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/geometry.hpp>
    #include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
    #include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>

    using namespace std;
    namespace bg = boost::geometry;
    namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

    typedef bg::model::point<int, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
    typedef std::pair<point, unsigned> value;

  struct ltstr
  {
bool operator()(const point &p1, const point &p2) const
{
    return (p1.get < 0 >() < p2.get < 0 >() || p1.get < 1 >() < p2.get < 1 >());
}
};


void main()
  {
vector<point> candidatePoints{ point(457, 184), point(457, 184), point(457, 184), point(457, 184), point(457, 184),
    point(456, 184), point(456, 184), point(456, 184), point(456, 184), point(456, 184),
    point(456, 184), point(457, 184), point(457, 184), point(457, 184), point(458, 184), point(459, 185) };

bgi::rtree< value, bgi::quadratic<16> > rtree;

set<point, ltstr> uniqueCandidatePoints;

for (int i = 0; i < candidatePoints.size(); ++i)
{
    int x = candidatePoints[i].get < 0 >();
    int y = candidatePoints[i].get < 1 >();
    uniqueCandidatePoints.insert(point(x, y));
    rtree.insert(make_pair(candidatePoints[i], i));
}

for (auto it = uniqueCandidatePoints.begin(); it != uniqueCandidatePoints.end(); ++it)
{
    std::vector<value> returnedValues;
    point currentItem = *it;
    rtree.query(bgi::satisfies([&](value const& v) {return bg::distance(v.first, currentItem) < 5; }),
        std::back_inserter(returnedValues));

    cout << "Current Item: " << currentItem.get < 0 >() << "," << currentItem.get < 1 >() << "Count: " << returnedValues.size() << endl;
} 

getchar();
```

}